# This array reassignment does not make sense

Tags: jscript

I saw this array reassignment that quite simply does not make sense to me..goes something like this.

```
var animals = ['dog','cat'];
console.log(animals[0]='big' + "" + animals[0]);

output being big dog.
```

Surely if you have reassigned first index to 'big', then surely the output should be big big. In my mind anyway, could someone explain how animals[0]retains it's original value after it has been reassigned with big.  please..

Comment: May I ask what context you're using JScript in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

animals[0] is dog. While executing console.log, first big and dog are concated. then this concated value is assigned to animals[0] and finally it is printed to console.

Assume it is like that:

```
var animals = ['dog','cat'];
animals[0]='big' + "" + animals[0]);
console.log(animals[0]);
```

Comment: thank you, I was just not seeing it like that at first.

Answer (score 0):

Precedence: `+` binds tighter than `=`, so

```
animals[0]='big' + "" + animals[0]
```

parses as

```
animals[0] = ('big' + "" + animals[0])
```